# char or smallint for a column with numeric codes?

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, sql-server-2019, physical-design

I have columns in my application that have values ​​that always have 4 digits, e.g. '0100' or '1230'. One of examples could be [Merchant Category Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merchant_category_code).

For the time being, I have set the type of this column to `char (4)`. I have many columns of this type. One of these types of columns is also included in nonclustered `UNIQUE` index. I would like to establish one approach to this type of column.

Is it better to use `char (4)` or maybe `smallint`, padding in the application by adding `' '` or  `0` to the beginning?

The table in which I have these columns is partitioned and will contain about 300 million records. `UPDATE` will probably not be executed on columns with this type. They will also not appear in `WHERE` (maybe sometimes in *ad hoc* reports).

Which data type should I choose?

> It's like a zip code, it can be numeric but you must store leading zeros

Exactly. I am thinking what is better approach in terms of performance. Also have to take into consideration that if I store it as `smallint`, the application code has to parse it to string and add leading zeros.

Answer (score 6):

The standard clearly says "four-digit code", which in my view means it should always contain 4 numeric characters, which in turn means the appropriate data type is `char(4)`.

If you want to ensure the code value adheres to ISO 18245, store it as `char(4)` in the database along with a check constraint.

Comment: why not smallint?

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy because unless you have business rules prohibiting codes starting with one or more `0`s, your code is a 4-character string, not a number.

Comment: @alroc it seems author is ready to adjust his application code to support smallint and asked what would be better in terms of performance

Comment: I would avoid a smallint because the data is not numeric (in the sense you would do arithmetic operations) and fields like that tend to evolve over time to include alpha characters.  Additionally, coded fields often have structure (i.e. first digit means X, second digit means Y)

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy what about every other system that expects a `char(4)`? When you buy a airplane ticket the number is `014-1234567890` where `014` is the airline code. Not `14`, `014`. Some systems may use `0141234567890` but none will use `14`. You really, really don't want to mix those two up, as everyone (airlines, travel agents, airports etc) use those specific digits as an identifier. If you used `smallint` you'd have to convert it back to `char(3)` at *every* point - all client applications, all imports, all exports.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what if author has only one application and really cares about its performance? First of all he asked about the performance. He may have dozen of such columns and millions of rows. Using of char(4) instead of smallint doubles data size. It's really hard to answer without more details about the data, app requirements and tests.

Comment: Anecdotally, having worked for an airline and one of the biggest merchants in the world, `CHAR` is always used over integers in this scenario. The above reasons are valid and frankly the potential for headaches and bugs is not worth the meager space savings in any scenario I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

The document says, `smallint` data type storage size is 2 Bytes
and `char(n)` data type storage size is every character equal to 1 byte.

> char [ ( n ) ] Fixed-size string data. n defines the string size in
> bytes and must be a value from 1 through 8,000. For single-byte
> encoding character sets such as Latin, the storage size is n bytes, and
> the number of characters that can be stored is also n.
>
> smallint  -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)  2 Bytes

The data type size consequently will affect your index size, query result size, memory use.

But on the other side, you have to think about performance losing when adding 0, (`'0121'`).

I think, there is no correct answer to the question. You can't decide which one is better without testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the best of both worlds, you can store it as CHAR(4) and add a persisted computed column to the table that uses the CONVERT function to store it as an int too. This way if you need to report off of it and use it as a predicate, it's more efficient and you can even create indexes on it.

That being said, I don't think CHAR(4) would cause much difference in performance in your predicates anyway even at 300 million records, but only way to know is to test it. Note the persisted computed column will make the table consume more disk space too since it's essentially a materialized column at that point.